# How to print/export calculation results from console in R studio?

Tags: r, dataframe, printing, console, export

I calculate many statistical analyses, such as Anova. The summary tables, and the posthoc test
results are displayed on the console in R studio. My problem is that how can I export/print 
results from the Console to tabular format (e.g. xls) into my working directory folder on my PC?
On the console, all calculation data are displayed in tabular format(-like) arrangement.

I have tried the code:

```
str(theSCRIPTforMYRESULTSontheCONSOLE)
sink("theSCRIPTforMYRESULTSontheCONSOLE.xls")
print(theSCRIPTforMYRESULTSontheCONSOLE$"ANYpartINmyRESULTS")
sink()
```

which works , however, very accidentally...

May I define a dataframe first? And then export?

Comment: Perhaps you would be interested in the `broom::tidy()`. It depends on what exactly you need in the output. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: There are R packages like openxlsx that allow you to write R data.frames into excel files.

Comment: MrFlick and Quarague22: thank you for your answers. I heard about openxlsx. However, my problem, now I can more clearly define, is that how can I export console data (resulted by an analysis), which is NOT data.frame (can be seen only on the console). Eq. results an anova, or posthoc test displayed the console only. I know the easiest way is ctrl C and ctrl v, but I want to do it using a script.